# How to connect a 5V submersible motor to Node MCU?

Tags: motor, nodemcu

I connected the D1,D2 pins of the the Node MCU to the positive and negative of a 5V submersible motor. I wrote the following code, its getting uploaded without any errors but the motor is not working. I tested the condition of the motor by connecting to a battery,it does work.the code:

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
    pinMode(D1,OUTPUT);
pinMode(D2,OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
digitalWrite(D1,HIGH);
digitalWrite(D2,HIGH);
}
```

Comment: A diagram of how things are physically connected would be very helpful here.

Comment: You might have to drive you motor using a transistor. If you motor does happen to operate using 5V (though, I'm pretty doubtful it will because a lot of motors require more voltage to operate), you will have to hook it up to the 5V rail and one of PWM pins (D1 for an example). Otherwise, if it requires more voltage, you will have to hook it up to a 9V battery and the PWM pin.

Comment: all pins are PWM on ESPs... You need to switch the load with the GPIO; DON'T drive the motor from the outputs themselves. a relay or nchan mosfet would work well.

Comment: You need an appropriate motor drive circuit, and an appopriate power source.  Motor power should never pass *through* the MCU board, and a "9v battery" is only suited to unusually low current motors, and even then not at all economical.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have got two issues here.

Firstly, as mentioned in the comments, you are driving the motor off the data pins so it will be getting less than 20mA which is almost certainly not enough to break the stall.  You need to use the digital pins to switch a MOSFET, transistor or relay (Electrical switch) and then that will switch on a larger supply directly from a "battery pack".  Have a Google for 'transistors' or 'relays' and see how they work, then you should get what I mean.

Secondly you seem to be using the pin names D1 and D2. There are a number of Node MCU boards out there but they all seem to have one thing in common and that is the pins labelled D1 and D2 on the board are generally not D1 and D2 in the code.

https://pradeepsinghblog.files.wordpress.com/2016/04/nodemcu_pins.png?w=924

If this is you board then unless you have a header file that does this for you, you should be using GPIO_5 and GPIO_4 for D1 and D2 (respectively).

Oh and the last thing, make sure you sub is leak proof :)